# I am learning to store some temperature values in a vector. When I execute and run it, it doesn't work, I don't know what the problem is

Tags: c++

I wrote the code from Stroustrup's book: [Programming: Principles and Practice using C++](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/0321992784), the program is executing but not working properly as expected. After putting input values it is expected to give mean and median temperature but there is no result.

See the image for my code:

[image]

Here I put 3 temperatures, but there is no result:

[image]

Comment: Please don't post images of your code. Instead, copy and paste it in the question (you can [edit] it anytime)

Comment: i tried to put code but it was showing an error that's why i put an image

Comment: Just copy-paste your code inside this -> ```your code here```.
And whats the problem with typing 10, 20, 30 and 40, that you instead upload an image to show us 4 numbers???

Comment: Your program doesn't know that you only want 3 values, you need to enter something invalid to mark end of input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your loop, `for (double temperature_first; cin >> temperature_first;)`, will only stop after you input an invalid value, for example a letter. If you continue to input numbers and spaces, it is an infinite loop.

Instead of reading from `cin` in a loop, you can use this to read a single line, and parse numbers from the string afterwards:

```
std::string line;
std::getline(std::cin, line);
```

Comment: The `cin >> temperature_first` loop will also end if you send an EOF (CTRL-D on Linux or CTRL-Z on Windows).

Comment: thanks for help. After putting something else the loop terminates and i get the correct result.:)